# Coefficients of series of an inverse function

Tags: real-analysis, functions

If $ a_n $ is $n^{th}$ term of a function and $b_n$ that of its unique inverse function

like e.g., in paired functions with infinite series

$$ log\; x / e^x,\; \tan x / \tan^{-1} x, $$

what function $ f $  in general binds them together like:

$$ f [ a_n(x),b_n(x)]=0? $$.

Answer (score 0):

From the equality $f(f^{-1}(x))=x$, you can get some complicated relations between the coefficients of $f$ and $f^{-1}$ thanks to Faa di Bruno formula : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fa%C3%A0_di_Bruno%27s_formula